# NixOS and ghcWithPackages - possibly incorrect information in the wiki

Tags: haskell, nixos

I'm referring here to the page: [Haskell - Nix Wiki](https://nixos.org/wiki/Haskell#Local_use_via_Nixpkgs_config), both the heading `Local use via Nixpkgs config` and `System-wide use via NixOS config`.

Here are the steps to replicate the problem: I download the NixOS-14.04 virtual appliance, load it in Virtual box, and try the System-wide use, so that my `configuration.nix` is:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  imports = [ <nixos/modules/installer/virtualbox-demo.nix> ];

  environment.systemPackages = [
      # other system packages
      (pkgs.haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (self : [
        self.haskellPlatform
    ]))
  ];
}
```

This is the output of [`nixos-rebuild test --show-trace -v`](http://lpaste.net/105842)

When I try the local option setting `.nixpkgs/config.nix`, here is the output of [`$ nix-env -iA nixos.pkgs.hsEnv`](http://lpaste.net/105844).

The errors seem to me very similar, and so I suspect there may be an error in `ghcWithPackages` .nix expression. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in `ghcWithPackages`. See https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/1438 for more information.

In short, the fix is to replace `ghcWithPackages` with `ghcWithPackagesOld`.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck! This worked. What should I do to edit the wiki?